# Creating a custom field view using theme_field template

Tags: entities

Folks - I'm trying to create a custom field view with custom content that utilises the standard `theme_field` template, to display in a node template.

I've tried to call the function programmatically e.g:

```
  $field_vars = array(
    'title_attributes' => 'test123',
    'label' => t('custom field label'),
    'items' => array('<p>This is a test</p>'),
    'classes' => 'test',
    'attributes' => FALSE
  );
  $my_field = theme('field', $field_vars); 
  print $my_field;
```

It returns the template, but none of the `$field_vars` are being used.  Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but if you only like to render a custom array with the field template this should work:

```
$field = array(
  '#theme' => 'field',
  '#field_type' => 'text',
  '#field_name' => 'temp_field',
  '#entity_type' => 'node',
  '#bundle' => null,
  '#items' => array(
     array(
       'value' => '',
     )
   ),
   0 => array(
     '#markup' => '<p>This is a test</p>'
   )
);
print theme_field(array(
  'label_hidden' => false,
  'label' => t('custom field label'),
  'items' => array($field),
  'classes' => 'test',
  'content_attributes' => '',
  'attributes' => '',
  'item_attributes' => ''
));
```

You can load one of your existing field using [`field_view_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) to check what data the renderable array contains. For example to load the `body` field from a node with an `id` equal to 1000 you could do like this:

```
$node = node_load(1000);
$field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'body');
print_r($field);
```

Comment: perfect! Cheers